# Run a command in Python 3.7 cli

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I have no experience in python, so spare me if it is a very silly question :)

I want to backup some repositories from GitHub and I found this library: https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-github-backup

I install it using pip and then I am trying to run it.
I started python and in python command line I entered these command:

```
github-backup -u 'MyUserName' -p 'MyPassword' 'MyOrganization'
```

But I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and it points to the end of MyUserName.

I am using Python 3.7 on windows 10.

How can I run this command in Python CLI?

Comment: It looks like that's a command for the Command Prompt and not an interactive python shell

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy So how can I use it? I am on windows and opened a CMD with admin prelivage.

Comment: If the package is already downloaded then for testing purposes just type `github-backup` in CMD and it should provide some information. If it says command not found then you probably installed the package in a different environment. Ok now if it provided some info, just go ahead and do `github-backup -u 'MyUserName' -p 'MyPassword' 'MyOrganization'`

Comment: It says that command not found.

Comment: Did you use an anaconda environment? or any virtual env for that matter?

Comment: No it is python 3.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194552/discussion-between-buckeye14guy-and-mans).